# Deserialize JSON string(geocode API's google) to object using JSON.NET c#

Tags: c#, json, google-maps

I ' m using the geocode API's Google, I can get the JSON string with all dates , but when i will convert it in a object, it do not work, it return anything,I'm using the JSON.NET, i'm doing something wrong ?

in all JSON data, I wanna just take the formatted_address.

json request : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=av.paulista&sensor=false%22

sorry my bad English

my main form: getting the JSON data(working)

```
private void btnConsumir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string address = txtAddress.Text ;

        string searchCode = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false";
        var JSONdata = "";


        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(searchCode);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            JSONdata = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        lblJSON.Text = JSONdata;//its a label
```

here i want get the formatted_address information on json:

```
[...]
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            JSONdata = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        lblJSON.Text = JSONdata;//its a label

        AddressObject addressObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<addressObject>(JSONdata);
        string result = addressObject.formatted_address;

        lblJSON.Text = result;
```

and this is my class object:

```
class AddressObject
    {
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }




    }
```

thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results that come back from the api are much more than `formatted_address`. You need to deserialize the entire graph, then pluck out what you want.

With the class structure below, you can do this:

```
Rootobject mapdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(JSONdata);
```

...

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Address_Components[] address_components { get; set; }
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

public class Address_Components
{
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
}
```